# in binary classification where class labels are {-1, 1} is preprocessing needed?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, preprocessing

In machine learning we convert labels using LabelEncoder to convert string ex:{"malignant", "benign"} -> {0, 1}

I am wondering if converting Labels to any other numbers matter, in my scenario to {-1,1}.
If it matters, reason provided will be helpful (or direction of helpful resource)!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `{0,1}` or `{-1,1}` labels depending on the output of your model. If you have a Sigmoid output use `{0,1}`, while TanH outputs work with `{-1,1}`.

No label choice is inherently right or wrong, as long as it's compatible with your model architecture and gives you good results.

---

EDIT:

In case of **logistic regression** you *must* use `{0,1}`, that is because this class of models has a Sigmoid output. Sigmoid function is always bounded in `[0,1]` and it can't take values outside of that range. It could never reach `-1` and training won't work.

Comment: Thanks you, so if I use logistic regression and labels are {-1, 1} then it affects performance? Could you explain the reason behind it?

Comment: nvm I found source here -> https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101560/tanh-activation-function-vs-sigmoid-activation-function

Comment: One more thing, what is the difference between converting {-1,1} to {0,1} then using sigmoid vs. using tanh from the start because I cannot find a way to implement tanh in sklearn.

Comment: @haneulkim you need to use `@username` to let the author realise you have asked another question of them.

Comment: @Leevo Oh and so no matter of label won't affect the performance?

Comment: @haneulkim In sklearn, it shouldn't matter at all: classifiers relabel as necessary.